# What "site" is Windows talking about?

Tags: security, windows-11, alert

Got this alert from Windows 11 (up to date)

[image]

<sup>*Image borrowed from [Windows support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-security-alert-message-doesnt-provide/05541d36-c2c7-465f-80fe-4ecf1744c64d)*</sup>

> "Do you want to allow files from this website to be copied to your computer?"

I wish I could answer the question, having absolutely no idea from what "site" this is about.

Context:

- Windows has almost nothing installed (iTunes, Chrome, I use Windows rarely)
- it has been checked for viruses, malware (by Defender)
- Nothing is opened
- the Task manager has the regular services running

Could be the LG service offering an update?

Any idea how to identify what "site" Windows is asking about?

Comment: What action are you performing when you get this alert? "Could be the LG service offering an update?" - What does an LG service have to do with anything? This alert should only happen if you attempt to copy content from a website (drag and drop) within a browser an image to the desktop. You also only get this warning if your machine is configured in such a way that it will happen.

Comment: Action: nothing. Windows boot, login ; the alert came a minute later (was working on my usual Linux workstation after the laptop boot). LG: in the past an LG service offered to update the bios and other stuff, I guess it could have started something in the background(?).

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag the bullseye icon over the message. This will find the process that issues this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Process Explorer from Sysinternals (published by Microsoft).

Once open, there is a target icon in the Process Explorer toolbar you can drag over windows to see their details, including what handles are open, how they were opened, etc. Using this you'll be able to see the details or the message you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, and very site dependent-  downloads repeat themselves when the browser is opened on a remembered page where the download started from. When a broswer is opened to remember all pages at startup, the download starts again and Windows 11 prompts you.

Go to the browser (most likely edge) and close all other tabs, then close the browser. Upon reopening the message should not appear.